# Prove that $P(∅) = 0$

Tags: probability

If $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ for every mutually exclusive events $A,B$ then prove **by using only the above property given ** that $P(∅)= 0$.

Comment: Hint: If the only set involved is the empty set, why not choose $A$ and $B$ to be the only set involved?

Comment: You could take the union of the full sample space and the empty set. i.e. $P(S\cup\varnothing)=1=$....

Answer (score 6):

Take $A = B = \emptyset$. Are these events mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Set $B = \varnothing$.  What is $A \cup \varnothing$?

**Edit:** If you also want $A$ and $B$ to be collectively exhaustive, i.e. $A \cup B$ is the entire space, then set $A = S$, where $S$ is the entire sample space.

Comment: You have 2 possible results, A and B , but they are mutually exclusive. That means that either A or B will happen but not both together at the same time. Can you prove by using only this as a clew that the probability of the empty set (∅) is 0?

Comment: @AggelosSfakianos "Mutually exclusive" just means they don't happen at the same time.  In which case my hint works.  Do you also need them to be [collectively exhaustive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectively_exhaustive_events), i.e. at least one of $A$ and $B$ occurs?